# Will bad thing happed if i remove an uid from my pgp key?

Tags: gnupg, privacy, openpgp

I added an photo uid to my openpgp keyring a few days ago.

If i want to update this image later, do i have to revoke the old one and keep it on the key? I don't want to because it would obviously make my public key grow larger and larger.

Or i can just delete the uid and pretend the old one never exist?

And what about ordinary uids?

When do i must revoke my uid, and when i can just delete it and leave it away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing bad will happen.

A PGP key is not a single file that gets overwritten, it's more like
a logbook that is progressively written with additional entries,
where old entries are at most crossed-out but are still present.

Your primary key is the first entry, and each "fact" that
is associated with the primary key (id, certification, subkey,
photo) gets appended to the bottom.

You can upload a new fact to the keyservers, including a fact that
repudiates a previous fact, and it is all appended to the log.
It's the client's job to sort through it and decide what bits are still relevant.

Note that the servers will still have your old picture, but clients
cannot know to ignore it unless you explicitly revoke it and upload the
revocation. This only marks the picture as invalid.
Clients will download it before they find out it has been revoked,
so other people will still be able to see it.